# Social logins and retaining access without having to authenticate every time...is it possible?

Tags: twitter, facebook, oauth

I am about to start a new project building a web UI with a lot of different functionality. Part of the functions however include the ability to update and access certain social media sites - Facebook and Twitter primarily.

I would like the user to login to the system and then also have the ability to manage multiple FB/Twitter accounts so that they can interact with these all from one place without having to authenticate every time they go to do something. For security reasons I obviously don't want to store passwords, but I'm not sure how to go about this one.

I know it's possible - does anyone have any pointers on how to go about this?

FYI - I'm programming in PHP, Javascript/Jquery.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the Facebook part. A good and easy way to do that is to use the Facebook PHP SDK ([see on github](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk)). So you will have something like :

```
require "facebook.php";
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => YOUR_APP_ID,
    'secret' => YOUR_APP_SECRET,
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();
```

If the user is logged in, then `$user` is his Facebook ID. You then have to check if you have a valid access token by making an API call :

- If it does not raise any exception, then you have a valid access token
- If it does, then you have to re-authenticate the user.

Here you go :

```
if ($user) {
  try {
    $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    $user = null;
  }
}
```

You need then to display the login or logout link :

```
<?php if ($user): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $facebook->getLogoutUrl() ?>">Logout of Facebook</a>
<?php else: ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $facebook->getLoginUrl() ?>">Login with Facebook</a>
<?php endif ?>
```

When the user is logged in and you have a valid access token, you can make API calls to get data from Facebook :

```
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
```

You may want to check the [example page of the Facebook PHP SDK](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php) which is well documented.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks for the quick response! If i'm reading right, I can use the access token to keep from re-authenticating. I also found something about requesting the offline_access permission to have an infinite expiry time (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) . I don't know why but FB integration has always been my Achilles heel - it just doesn't seem straight forward to me. Thanks again!

Comment: The access token is stored in the user cookie so you can make API calls as long as the token does not expire on Facebook side (a few hours) and the user does not log out Facebook. When the token expire, the user will have to click on "Login with Facebook" again, but nothing will be asked to him as he is logged in Facebook and he has given his authorization. If you ask for the `offline_access` permission when generating the login link (`$facebook->getLoginUrl($args)` whith `$args['scope'] = offline_acces`), the issued token will never expire : you may want to store it in your database.